# wxpython cut copy and paste throughout the application

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm developing a small application with multiple TextCtrl and ComboBox widgets. I want that when I press the key Ctrl-C Ctrl-V and Ctrl-X I get the usual behaviour of copying, pasting and cutting in the appropriate entry.

What I obtain right now is that, while I can right-click and have the text copd/past/cutd, I can't through the keybindings or the menu entries. How can I obtain this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu keybindings work by default with Alt-first_menu_letter -> submenu_first_letter.
The menu event of the selected item should bind the corresponding event handler:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_copy, self.copy)
```

for a copy method, you first select the text you want to copy with the mouse. Then you can get the widget that is focused (the specific textcontrol with the selected string to be copied) with:

```
widget = self.FindFocus()
```

in this way now you can get the selected string from that widget:

```
self.copied = widget.GetStringSelection()
```

And the same has to be done for pasting the copied text in the textctrl you situate the cursor.
Here you have a working example:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.tctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.tctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.test = wx.Menu()
        self.copy = wx.MenuItem(self.test, wx.NewId(), "copy", "is_going to copy", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        self.test.AppendItem(self.copy)
        self.paste = wx.MenuItem(self.test, wx.NewId(), "paste", "will paste", wx.ITEM_NORMAL)
        self.test.AppendItem(self.paste)
        self.menubar.Append(self.test, "Test")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_copy, self.copy)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_paste, self.paste)

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_2.Add(self.tctrl_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_2.Add(self.tctrl_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(sizer_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def on_copy(self, event): 
        widget = self.FindFocus()
        self.copied = widget.GetStringSelection()

    def on_paste(self, event): 
        widget = self.FindFocus()
        widget.WriteText(self.copied)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```